# undefined method `strong' when trying bundle exec rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Ruby 2.2.2 and Rails 4.2.3.

The commands I did are:

```
 rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
 bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

The error I got is:

```
 rake aborted!
 StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

 undefined method `strong' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition:0x00000005b72028>/home/clemant/tutorials/test2/db/migrate/20150709221657_create_users.rb:5:in `block in change'
```

My migration file:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.strong :email

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

My database.yml file is:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Please post your migration file and database.yml file

Comment: Yes take a look in your database.yml, regarding the error message it seems you have something wrong in here.

Comment: its obvious that you need to change t.strong :email
 to t.string :email

Comment: I wonder why it creates a migration file with `t.strong` when you have given `rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string`. It should create a correct migration file unless you open and edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your migration file, you have written: `t.strong :email`.

It should be rectified as follows:

```
t.string :email
```